# Cannot load app within Canvas

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

My application is fully working at an url like myapp.com/ ,  the base directory is automatically loading index.html

When I edit the application to be a canvas app and setting its canvas url to myapp.com/ 
When accessing the page http://apps.facebook.com/myapp it gives me an error:

```
POST http://myapp.com/ 404 (Not Found)
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

Anyone have an idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: i think you have to place your complete code so that we can able to check completely

Answer (score 0):

'X-Frame-Options' is your clue.  This is a header your webserver is sending out. Be sure you send the correct

See also:

[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)